# Save Job offers in wp_options or extra table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, plugins

Hi Wordpress Developer,

I am writing a Job offering Plugin for a client and I was asking myself if it is more efficient to create a extra table in the mysql db for the jobs (id,title, hours, description, €, city) or save them into wp_options (multiple arrays). How fast is wp_options if there are 100 jobs in the big array?

Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store them as a big array in wp_options, it would be fast since the whole array would be serialized/deserialized into JSON and stored as one record. However, IMO, it's difficult to troubleshoot if something goes wrong. Additionally, it's difficult to modify the schema down the road (i.e. you'd have to write a special script to migrate data from old schema to new schema). I would suggest that you create an extra table.